# android outofmemory while reading epub file

Tags: android, exception, epub

In my application i am reading **`epub`** file when big size epub is reading it's give me can any one help me about this:

**Error:**

```
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698): FATAL EXCEPTION: Background
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.util.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:79)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.util.IOUtil.toByteArray(IOUtil.java:43)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:114)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.util.ResourceUtil.createResource(ResourceUtil.java:64)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readResources(EpubReader.java:188)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:94)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:53)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:37)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at com.fastreader.TextReader.StringSpilitFunction(TextReader.java:362)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at com.fastreader.TextReader$4$1$1.run(TextReader.java:126)
02-01 09:25:06.814: E/AndroidRuntime(26698):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: why you read whole file? why not do it in portions, step by step, as your app need it? there is no reason to read whole thing if you only process one piece of it at the time (for showing one page or any other purpose).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be loading the whole file at once, which is probably more than your app memory limit.

Try loading chunks of the file into an array or something similar and dispose of the chunks you don't need. You most certainly won't need to use the whole file at once, because there's no way you could show it all on screen. On the other hand, loading a page at a time should be enough for most reasonable purposes (like, for example, showing it on screen).

Even if you're into something more exotic, like language analysis, you could load even smaller chunks of the file and analyse them one at a time.

The epub library you're using must be able to give you something more manageable than the whole file. There was this `readEpubLazy` method for this exact purpose.